# Not receiving document _id as an argument in AutoForm method-update

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have an AutoForm with this options:

```
{{
    #autoForm 
    collection=articulosColecction 
    id="articulos_modificar" 
    doc=articuloToModificar
    type="method-update"
    meteormethod="areas.update"
    singleMethodArgument=true // Recommended here 
}}
```

singleMethodArgument=true is Recommended [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#method-update)

And my method is this:

```
export const update = new ValidatedMethod({
    name: 'areas.update',
    validate: null,
    run(doc) {
    console.log(doc._id);
    Areas.update({ _id: doc._id }, doc.modifier)
  }
});
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#method-update) says:

> 2. If you set singleMethodArgument=true as a form attribute, your method will be called with a single object argument with _id and modifier properties. You should do this if using the mdg:validated-method package.

But `console.log(doc._id);` is outputting `undefined` and I've tried `console.log(doc)' and it outputs only the modifier object.

What is going? Is it something wrong with my AutoForm?

Comment: I had the wrong collection on the `collection` argument of the `autoForm` form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meteormethod argument should call a [Meteor.Method](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#what-is-a-method).

you should have define:

```
Meteor.methods({
  areas.update(updateData){
    check(updateData._id, String);
    check(updateData.modifier, Object);
    //do other stuff here
  }
});
```

inside the method you can use the data._id and modifier.